# action.class for current user

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4, jobeet

i learn Symfony 1.4 with Jobeet. I made Jobeet and system login for user. Now i would like add possibility edit own affiliate.

```
<?php

class jobActions extends sfActions
{
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->jobeet_job_list = Doctrine::getTable('JobeetJob')
      ->createQuery('a')
      ->execute();
  }

  public function executeShow(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->jobeet_job = Doctrine::getTable('JobeetJob')->find($request->getParameter('id'));
    $this->forward404Unless($this->jobeet_job);
  }

  public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->form = new JobeetJobForm();
  }

  public function executeCreate(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod('post'));

    $this->form = new JobeetJobForm();

    $this->processForm($request, $this->form);

    $this->setTemplate('new');
  }

  public function executeEdit(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->forward404Unless($jobeet_job = Doctrine::getTable('JobeetJob')->find($request->getParameter('id')), sprintf('Object jobeet_job does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('id')));
    $this->form = new JobeetJobForm($jobeet_job);
  }

  public function executeUpdate(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->forward404Unless($request->isMethod('post') || $request->isMethod('put'));
    $this->forward404Unless($jobeet_job = Doctrine::getTable('JobeetJob')->find($request->getParameter('id')), sprintf('Object jobeet_job does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('id')));
    $this->form = new JobeetJobForm($jobeet_job);

    $this->processForm($request, $this->form);

    $this->setTemplate('edit');
  }

  public function executeDelete(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $request->checkCSRFProtection();

    $this->forward404Unless($jobeet_job = Doctrine::getTable('JobeetJob')->find($request->getParameter('id')), sprintf('Object jobeet_job does not exist (%s).', $request->getParameter('id')));
    $jobeet_job->delete();

    $this->redirect('job/index');
  }

  protected function processForm(sfWebRequest $request, sfForm $form)
  {
    $form->bind($request->getParameter($form->getName()));
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
      $jobeet_job = $form->save();

      $this->redirect('job/edit?id='.$jobeet_job['id']);
    }
  }
}
```

In actions.class executeIndex i can add where:

```
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
    $this->jobeet_job_list = Doctrine::getTable('JobeetJob')
      ->createQuery('a')
      ->where('id = ?', $id) //$id i have in session, this working OK
      ->execute();
  }
```

how can i make similarly with executeEdit? in database i have field user_id, which added a news. I would like to edit can only author this news. thanks for help!

Comment: Do you have module where each user can add news?Users can add news in frontend or backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its editing the job what you are trying to do, you have to find the job you want to edit and create a form initialized with the object. Something like (i'm skipping all the parameter checking bits, obviously you have to make sure that the id is in the request, the user is logged and the job retrieved exists and is owned by the user):

```
$user_id = $this->getUser()->getId(); // if you are logged and getId is defined in your myUser class

$job_id = $request->getParameter('id', false);

$job = Doctrine::getTable('JobeetJob')->find($job_id);

if ($job['owner_id'] == $user_id)
{
  $this->form = new JobeetJobForm($job);
}
```